# How to Search Specific values in a Vector and update it in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hi! Thanks in advance...

I am doing a code to add a string value in a Vector and show that value on a textfield and after, display that value on the editfield. And I want to make an event for that editfield to update the vector value for the Blackberry I want to make a code.

I make one customeTextField and one button field on clicking this button field the value enter on customeTextField is added to vector and create a new customeTextfield which holds the enter string.

I want to event for the another customeTextField which will update the string and vector element in blackberry.

(Blackberry code is necessary)

Comment: you can make a `update button` and when you click on update get the `String value` you have saved into `Vector`. compare that if they are same dont update, else update the String value.

Comment: Consider posting your own code before asking others to post theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the index of element on the focus listener of the text field then make a code for the fieldchange listener and take the index of element and write the setElement for the vector method.